# How do I code the removal of duplicated files in a zip folder before reading?

Tags: r

Say I have a zip file `data.zip` that contains the following files:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 1
  Name                  
  <chr>                 
1 data/data/data.csv    
2 data/data/info.csv    
3 data/data/info (1).csv
```

I want to read only the non-duplicated files, `data.csv` and `info.csv`. I tried the following:

```
library(tidyverse)

files <- unzip(data.zip, list=T)

fileExt <- c("data", "info")

filesNoDup <- files$Name[!duplicated(str_detect(files$Name, fileExt))]

filesRead <- map(filesNoDup, read_csv)
```

But that doesn't work because my `fileExt` vector is shorter than the `files` vector. How can I read only the non-duplicate files without manually changing them and/or manually removing them from the folder?

**Edit**
I want to read the most recent file `info (1). csv`. How to read the file with the highest number, perhaps?

Comment: Haven't done something like this before. Have you tried `files[! grepl("\\(\\d+\\)", files)]
`?

Comment: @Friede Small correction: `files[!grepl("\\(\\d+\\)", files$Name), ]` works, I have tried it.

Comment: Brilliant, it worked! Feel free to post it and I'll mark it as the answer. Can you explain what all those back slashes are for? Are the first two for the first two paths, i.e., data/data/? And what is the d+? Thank you so much!!

Comment: I find this question horrifying.  Just because two filenames are similar, what makes you sure the files are duplicated?  Even if they are different versions of the same file, why wouldn't you want the newer one?

Comment: That is an excellent point, I do want the most recent one, and unfortunately the way the data is submitted, they don't have different dates, so I can't filter by the most recent date. I'll need to see if I can't alter the above code to detect the file I want `files[grepl("\\(\\d+\\)", files$Name), ]` and remove the file detected by `files[!grepl("\\(\\d+\\)", files$Name), ]`.